# gpg not working pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8 while decrypt inside a while loop

Tags: linux, gpg

My gpg is working fine

```
gpg -c /home/abcd/test.text
```

Its asking my the password 2 times and works fine but it gave the error when I was trying

```
while IFS="," read -r rec_column1 rec_column2
do
gpg -c /home/abcd/test.txt
done < <(tail -n +1 list.csv)
```

any help

```
can't connect to `/root/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file or directory
pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8
                                                   pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8
```

Comment: Title says "decryption", which would be `gpg -d ...` but the command being given is `gpg -c ...` ("symmetrically encrypt"). Which is it? Also, why repeatedly do this to the same file in a loop?

Comment: For different file also gave same error